# I want to continously draw a line that can be turned with key press

Tags: python, pygame

Im new to programming and want to practice by recreating tron in pygame. But i can't figure out how to draw i line that will continuously go forward and be turned by key a press. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You may wanna look at snake game tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/K5F-aGDIYaM).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You should give it a go first, and when something doesn't work, then ask for help, so we know what you have tried and dont explain how to do something you already have done.

nevertheless, you want a player that travels in the same direction, so you need a variable for the players position on the screen and its direction/velocity

so

```py
player_pos = [200, 200] #start position
player_vel = [1, 0] #start moving to the right
```

now in the game loop, you can draw the player and update the position

```py
while running: #game loop
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), player_pos, 5) #draw the player
    
    player_pos[0] += player_vel[0] #update the x position of the player
    player_pos[1] += player_vel[1] #update the y position of the player
```

now you want to change the direction when a key is pressed, i used wasd for movement.

```py
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # stop game loop
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player_vel = [1, 0] #move
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player_vel = [-1, 0]
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player_vel = [0, -1]
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player_vel = [0, 1]
```

pressing play with this makes the player move really fast so to slow it down, we can limit the fps

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#in game loop

clock.tick(100) #limit it to 100 fps
```

here is all the code together

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500)) #setup the screen

player_pos = [200, 200]  # start position
player_vel = [1, 0]  # start moving to the right

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
running = True
while running:  # game loop
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), player_pos, 5)  # draw the player

    player_pos[0] += player_vel[0]  # update the x position of the player
    player_pos[1] += player_vel[1]  # update the y position of the player

    clock.tick(100)

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # stop game loop
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            break
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player_vel = [1, 0]
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player_vel = [-1, 0]
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player_vel = [0, -1]
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player_vel = [0, 1]
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why did you choose w,a,s,d keys and not the arrows?  I see a few people do this, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Kingsley Most games use wasd to move so i guess im just use to that. Also faster to type K_d instead of K_RIGHT

Comment: thanks, you helped me get out of a block. I just have one question, why did you write running = True when you could have just used True

Comment: @hibob yes i used to do that and used `sys.exit()` but my programming teacher did not like it and said my grade would go down for that, also it stops accidental infinite loops, now its just a habit. Also makes it slightly easier to read for non programmers which means nothing but i like to do